# Traning neural networks with extension R in NetLogo

Tags: r, netlogo

I am creating a supply chain simulation with NetLogo. I am putting a list of lists from NetLogo to R, which is represented by distributor ID (agents who) and sales history (sales of all previous ticks). In R I train my neural network and make predictions. When I put back the answer in the same format list of lists. I need to specify which result goes to which agent. However, I do not know how to do it in NetLogo. I assume that there should be a function to do that, but as I understand the functions are programmed with Java and I would need to assign the values inside the raw code and not in the NetLogo environment. Moreover, I think that this training and predictions occurs multiple times (for each agent) and not only once.

Variable example:
[ [0] [ 100 200 300 100 200] ]
[ [1] [ 200 300 100 100 200] ]

Where the first index is agents who index and the second is the agent's sales history.

Maybe someone could explain how NetLogo and R can be combined for computational purpose and not only statistical analysis and plotting? I assume that NetLogo is similar to parallel programming, while my style of R programming is more linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part of your question is beyond me (and may be too broad for typical Stack Overflow questions- I'm not sure you'll get a useful answer here). However, maybe this example would get you in the right direction as to what you're trying to do.

I assume you're using the `[r]` extension as in your previous question, so using this setup:

```
extensions [r]

turtles-own [ rand-num ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 10 [
    set rand-num random 5
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

In this example, turtles have a `rand-num` instead of your sales history, but the concept is the same. First, build the list of lists where first index is the turtle `[who]` and the second is `[rand-num]`, then output it to r (note that I also `sort` the list, but that is just for clarity and not actually needed):

```
to go

  let l_list map [ i ->
    list i [rand-num] of turtle i
  ] ( sort [ who ] of turtles )

  r:put "list1" l_list

  show r:get "list1"
```

Next, use `r:eval` to do whatever you need to do to the values in r- in this example I'm just using `lapply` to square the `rand-num` value (`x[[2]]`)- but make sure to return `x`:

```
let modified_list ( r:get "lapply(list1, function(x) { x[[2]] <- x[[2]]^2; return(x)})" )
```

Now, to assign the turtles the modified values, use Netlogo's `foreach` to iterate over the modified list and ask the turtle of index 0 (`turtle item 0 x`) to set its `rand-num` to index 1 (`set rand-num item 1 x`):

```
  foreach modified_list [ x ->
    ask turtle item 0 x [
      set rand-num item 1 x
    ]
  ]

end
```

If you check the `sort [rand-num] of turtles` before and after running go, you should see the `rand-num` of each turtle is squared after go is called.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, I agree that my second part is too broad. I still need much to learn when working with machine learning and programming.